# How to make a mix constant string that has ascii text as well as ascii hex codes in it?

Tags: java, android, string, hex, ascii

I want to define a constant string as following:
"Hello World$1F"

Where the '$1F' is the ASCII hex code.
Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific; where did "$1F" come from, and what is the problem with the `String` literal as you have written it?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is:

```
"Hello World\u001F"
```

Comment: can you explain what is \u001F?

Comment: That's how you represent any 16-bit Unicode character in Java -- \uXXXX, where XXXX is the hex value for the character. The ASCII range of Unicode is 0000 to 007F.

Answer (score 0):

Java String, char, Character use the UTF-16 encoding of the Unicode character set. (Just in like JavaScript, .NET, VB4, NCHAR, NVARCHAR, ….) Any similarity to ASCII is rarely relevant.

So, by $1F you must mean the Unicode codepoint [U+001F](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f/index.htm), which is represented in a String literal as the single UTF-16 code unit "\u001F". (Note: You can visualize it using a control picture character ␟, too.)